# warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data'

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// Program to generate random numbers, using an array

int main() {
int arr[50];
int i;

srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    arr[i] = rand() % 50;
    printf("arr[%d] = %d\t", i, arr[i]);
}
_getch();
return 0;
```

}

I'm getting this warning:

> (12): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data.

Comment: You need to include the correct header file that declares [the `time` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time).

Comment: You have other problems though, since you seem to have forgotten that array indexes are *zero-based*. I.e. the valid indexes of an array of 50 elements is `0` to `49` (inclusive). Not that you need an array in the code you show, really.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to have the array within the range of 1 to 50 instead of 0-49.

Comment: And the question after your edit is *very* different. And you forgot to change your title. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Regarding the array, ***why***? Especially since it means you (currently) ***will*** go out of bounds of it?

Comment: I understand, I will change it over now (new to programming - silly mistake).

Answer (score 2):

`srand` wants an `unsigned int` as argument, but `time` returns a `time_t` which is a larger type than `unsigned int` on your platform, hence the warning *possible loss of data.*

In this case the warning can be ignored, because you actually just want to give a seemingly random value to `srand`.

To get rid of the warning you can cast the value returned by `time` to `unsigned int`:

```
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
```